# ElasticSearch Max of Max?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search for max time (Recent entries), out of those max entries I want one with max value. 
I've tried various types of nesting on aggregation, using filters,etc. but it doesn't seem to work out. Any help?

Example :-

Mapping -

```
{
  "trytime": {
    "mappings": {
      "value": {
        "properties": {
          "time": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Values :-

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "trytime",
        "_type": "value",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "time": 9,
          "value": 5
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "trytime",
        "_type": "value",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "time": 6,
          "value": 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "trytime",
        "_type": "value",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "time": 9,
          "value": 6
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "trytime",
        "_type": "value",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "time": 9,
          "value": 9
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need the maximum time and maximum value corresponding to such time (There will be multiple values corresponding to a particular time).

Query :-

```
GET /trytime/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs":{
    "max_Value": {
      "max": {
        "field": "value"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": ___NEED-MAX-TIME-VALUE-HERE___
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: You need to provide your current query, what you tried so far, and what fails, to get replies.

Comment: please provide your mappings, schema settings, example documents and queries you have tried so far. Thats the only way we can help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this nested aggregation should give you 3 latest times and for each time you get the max value. Set size to one if want only one result.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "times": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "time",
        "size": 3,
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_vals": {
          "max": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this could be achieved by date histogram aggregation as well.